# Need to add avatar and username to post

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

So, I'm trying to add the user avatar and username to my addPost. I've tried everything I can think of but nothing is working.

I've Tried;

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.avatar;
```

But that doesn't work, I'm assuming it's because "avatar" or "username" isn't firebase specific properties for auth.

I've also tried;

```
get uid() {
    return firebase.auth().currentUser;
}
```

and then adding to addPost

```
avatar: this.uid.avatar,
username: this.uid.username
```

That doesn't work either.

I just need the user avatar and username to be available when called on the home screen.

```
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, FlatList, Platform, TouchableNativeFeedback, TouchableOpacity, Image, Button } from "react-native";
import Fire from '../../Fire';
import UsernameText from '../../components/Text/DefaultUsernameText';
import CreatedAtText from '../../components/Text/CreatedAtText';
import ThoughtTitleText from '../../components/Text/DefaultThoughtTitle';
import Colors from  '../../constants/Colors';
import moment from 'moment';

 let TouchableCmp = TouchableOpacity;
if (Platform.OS === 'android' && Platform.Version >= 21) {
    TouchableCmp = TouchableNativeFeedback;
}


export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    
 state = {
   latestPost: [],
   
}

displayLatestPost = (latestPost) => {
    this.setState({latestPost: latestPost});
    console.log("latest Post " + this.state.latestPost);
}

componentDidMount(){
   Fire.shared.getPosts(this.displayLatestPost);
   console.log("This is the displayLatestPost " + this.state.latestPost);
   
}



  
renderLatestPost = (post) => {
    return (
        <View>

        <TouchableCmp onPress={() => {}} style={{flex: 1}}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.infoText}>

            <Image style={styles.userAvatar}>{post.avatar}</Image>
                <UsernameText style={styles.name} >{post.username}</UsernameText>
    <CreatedAtText style={styles.timestamp}>{moment(post.timestamp).fromNow()}</CreatedAtText>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.container} >
    <ThoughtTitleText style={styles.feedItem}>{post.thoughtTitle}</ThoughtTitleText>
            </View>
        
        </View>
        </TouchableCmp>
        </View>
    );
};

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
             <Button
                    onPress={() => {
                        Fire.shared.signOut();
                    }}
                    title="Log out"
                />

            <FlatList
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                style={styles.feed}
                data={this.state.latestPost}
                renderItem={( {item, index }) =>
                 this.renderLatestPost(item, index)
                } 
            />
        </View>
    );
}
   
        
    
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.background
    },
    feed: {
        marginHorizontal: 16
    },
     feedItem: {
        borderRadius: 5,
        padding: 2,
        flexDirection: "row",
        marginVertical: 2
    },
    name: {
        fontSize: 15,
        fontWeight: "500",
        color: "#454D65"
    },
    timestamp: {
        fontSize: 11,
        color: "#C4C6CE",
        marginTop: 4
    },
    post: {
        marginTop: 16,
        fontSize: 14,
        color: "#838899"
    },
    postImage: {
        width: undefined,
        height: 150,
        borderRadius: 5,
        marginVertical: 16
    },
    container: {
        flex:1,
        borderRadius: 10,
        padding:15,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        alignItems: 'flex-end'
        },
        thought: {
        color: '#666',
        fontSize: 18,
        marginBottom: 5,
        alignItems: 'center' 
        },
     
        infoText:{
            flexDirection: "row"
        },
        // icons: {
        //     flexDirection: 'row'
        // },
        userAvatar: {
            backgroundColor: Colors.subheadings,
            borderColor: Colors.accent,
            borderWidth:3.5, 
            
            backgroundColor: Colors.maintext,
            marginEnd: 15,
            width: 35,
            height: 35,
            borderRadius: 20,
        } 
});
```

Here's my Fire.js

```
import FirebaseKeys from "./config/FirebaseKeys";
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import '@firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/database';
import '@firebase/firestore';
import "firebase/storage";
require("firebase/firestore");

class Fire {
constructor() {
    firebase.initializeApp(FirebaseKeys);
}

getPosts = async (displayLatestPost) => {
    const post = await 

this.firestore.collection('thoughts').orderBy('timestamp', '  desc').limit(10).get()
    
    let postArray =[]
    post.forEach((post) => {
        
        postArray.push({id: post.id, ...post.data()})
    })

  displayLatestPost(postArray)  
}


addPost = async ({ thoughtTitle, thoughtText, localUri, avatar, username}) => {
    const remoteUri = await this.uploadPhotoAsync(localUri, `photos/${this.uid}/${Date.now()}`);
   
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
         this.firestore
            .collection("thoughts")
            .add({
                uid: this.uid,
                thoughtTitle,
                thoughtText,
                image: remoteUri,
                timestamp: this.timestamp,
                
            })
            .then(ref => {
                res(ref);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                rej(error);
            });
    });
};

uploadPhotoAsync = (uri, filename) => {
    return new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
        const response = await fetch(uri);
        const file = await response.blob();

        let upload = firebase
            .storage()
            .ref(filename)
            .put(file);

        upload.on(
            "state_changed",
            snapshot => {},
            err => {
                rej(err);
            },
            async () => {
                const url = await upload.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
                res(url);
            }
        );
    });
};

createUser = async user => {
    let remoteUri = null;

    try {
        await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
        
        let db = this.firestore.collection("users").doc(this.uid);

        db.set({
            username: user.username,
            email: user.email,
            avatar: null
        });

        if (user.avatar) {
            remoteUri = await this.uploadPhotoAsync(user.avatar, `avatars/${this.uid}`);

            db.set({ avatar: remoteUri }, { merge: true });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        alert("Error: ", error);
    }
}; 



updateProfile = async user => {
    let remoteUri = null;

    try {
        let db = 
this.firestore.collection("users").doc(this.uid);

        db.update({
            username: user.username,
            email: user.email,
            avatar: null
        });

        if (user.avatar) {
            remoteUri = await this.uploadPhotoAsync(user.avatar, `avatars/${this.uid}`);

            db.set({ avatar: remoteUri }, { merge: true });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        alert("Error: ", error);
    }  

}

signOut = () => {
    firebase.auth().signOut();
};

get firestore() {
    return firebase.firestore();
}

 /*  get username(){
    return firebase.auth().currentUser.username;
  } */

get uid() {
    return (firebase.auth().currentUser || {}).uid;
}

  /*   get avatar(){
    return firebase.auth().currentUser.avatar;
  } */


get timestamp() {
     return Date.now();  
}



}

 Fire.shared = new Fire();
 export default Fire;
```

Comment: Don't guess about the properties of user objects - use the API documentation to discover what's available. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User

Answer (score 1):

I hope the following information helps.

You can store Name & Profile Picture URL like this:

```js
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

// Update User Profile
user.updateProfile({
  displayName: "Jane Doe",
  photoURL: "https://example.com/1hdfabSesfE/profile.jpg"
}).then(function() {
  // Update successful.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});

// Use these parameters inside the add post function
var profilePicture = user.photoURL;
var name = user.displayName;
```

Comment: My current code has avatar and username... can I update the firebase user object with this code? Can you show me an example?  Really sorry, been app developing since March.

Comment: Yes, so the parameters `avatar` and `username` are not valid parameters in a Firebase User Object. Refer to this link for the right parameters and documentation on creating & updating users. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile

Let me know if this clarifies your issue,

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm one step closer to getting my displayName and photoURL to appear with the posts.

Comment: Hey, Blessing Platinum-Williams, it would be great for the community if you mark this answer as valid since it seems it was helpful.

Comment: I have for some reason it hasn't registered.

Answer (score 0):

So, I changed my createUser and updateUser

```
createUser = async user => {
let remoteUri = null;

try {
    await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
    
    let db = this.firestore.collection("users").doc(this.uid);

    db.set({
        displayName: user.displayName,
        email: user.email,
        photoURL: null
    });

    if (user.photoURL) {
        remoteUri = await this.uploadPhotoAsync(user.photoURL, `avatars/${this.uid}`);

        db.set({ photoURL: remoteUri }, { merge: true });
    }
} catch (error) {
    alert("Error: ", error);
}
}; 



updateProfile = async user => {
let remoteUri = null;

try {
    let db = this.firestore.collection("users").doc(this.uid);
   

    db.update({
      displayName: user.displayName,
      photoURL: user.photoURL
    });

    if (user.photoURL) {
        remoteUri = await this.uploadPhotoAsync(user.photoURL, `avatars/${this.uid}`);

        db.set({ photoURL: remoteUri }, { merge: true });
    }
} catch (error) {
    alert("Error: ", error);
}  

}
```

Then I changed my addPost

```
    addPost = async ({ thoughtTitle, thoughtText, localUri, photoURL, displayName}) => {
    const remoteUri = await this.uploadPhotoAsync(localUri, `photos/${this.uid}/${Date.now()}`);
   

    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        
         this.firestore
            .collection("thoughts")
            .add({
                uid: this.uid,
                displayName,
                photoURL,
                thoughtTitle,
                thoughtText,
                image: remoteUri,
                timestamp: this.timestamp,
                
            })
            .then(ref => {
                res(ref);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                rej(error);
            });
    });
};
```

Thanks for all the help - It's working!.

Here's my account screen where I update the displayName and photoURL

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, Image, TextInput, TouchableOpacity} from 
 "react-native";
import Fire from "../../Fire";
import { MaterialIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons"
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";
import UserPermissions from "../../utilities/UserPermissions";
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';
//import Avatar from '../../components/User/Avatar';

     export default class AccountScreen extends React.Component {
      state = {
      user: {},
      updatedUser: {
       photoURL: null,
       displayName: ""
      }
      };

    unsubscribe = null;

    componentDidMount() {
    const user = this.props.uid || Fire.shared.uid;

    this.unsubscribe = Fire.shared.firestore
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user)
        .onSnapshot(doc => {
            this.setState({ user: doc.data() });
        });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
}


    handleUpdate = () => {
     Fire.shared.updateProfile(this.state.updatedUser);
    };

     handlePickAvatar = async () => {
    UserPermissions.getCameraPermission();

  let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [1, 1],
      quality: 0.1
  });

  if (!result.cancelled) {
      this.setState({ updatedUser: { ...this.state.updatedUser, photoURL: result.uri 
  } });
  }
   };




      render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <KeyboardAwareScrollView
            style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%' }}
            keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
         <View style={styles.container}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.avatarContainer} onPress=. 
    {this.handlePickAvatar}>
                    <Image
                        source={
                            this.state.updatedUser.photoURL
                                ? { uri: this.state.user.photoURL }
                                : require("../../assets/tempAvatar.jpg")
                        }
                        style={styles.avatar}
                        /> 
                        
                        
                     <MaterialIcons 
                     name="photo-camera" 
                     size={40} color="grey" 
                     style={{ marginTop: 6, marginLeft: 2 }} 
                     />         
                   </TouchableOpacity>
                    
               <View>
                   <TextInput
                        style={styles.border}
                        placeholder= "change username"
                        onChangeText={displayName => this.setState({ updatedUser: { ...this.state.updatedUser, displayName } })}
                        value={this.state.updatedUser.displayName}
                    ></TextInput>
                </View>
               <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleUpdate}>
                <MaterialIcons name="check" size={24} color="black" />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View> 
          

        </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        </View>
    );
}
  }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'

  },
profile: {
    marginTop: 64,
    alignItems: "center"
},
avatarContainer: {
    shadowColor: "#151734",
    shadowRadius: 30,
    shadowOpacity: 0.4
},
avatar: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 68
},
name: {
    marginTop: 24,
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: "600"
},
statsContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    margin: 32
},
stat: {
    alignItems: "center",
    flex: 1
},
statAmount: {
    color: "#4F566D",
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: "300"
},
statTitle: {
    color: "#C3C5CD",
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: "500",
    marginTop: 4
},
border: {
    width: 200,
    margin: 10,
    padding: 15,
    fontSize: 16,
    borderColor: '#d3d3d3',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  });
```

Here's my Home.js

```
  import React from "react";
  import { View, StyleSheet, FlatList, Platform, 
  TouchableNativeFeedback, 
  TouchableOpacity, Image, Button } from "react-native";
  import Fire from '../../Fire';
  import UsernameText from ' 
  ../../components/Text/DefaultUsernameText';
  import CreatedAtText from '../../components/Text/CreatedAtText';
  import ThoughtTitleText from ' 
  ../../components/Text/DefaultThoughtTitle';
  import Colors from  '../../constants/Colors';
  import moment from 'moment';

  let TouchableCmp = TouchableOpacity;
  if (Platform.OS === 'android' && Platform.Version >= 21) {
  TouchableCmp = TouchableNativeFeedback;
  }


 export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

 state = {
    latestPost: [],

  }

 displayLatestPost = (latestPost) => {
 this.setState({latestPost: latestPost});
 console.log("latest Post " + this.state.latestPost);
}

componentDidMount(){
Fire.shared.getPosts(this.displayLatestPost);
console.log("This is the displayLatestPost " + this.state.latestPost);

 }




 renderLatestPost = (post) => {
   return (
     <View>

     <TouchableCmp onPress={() => {}} style={{flex: 1}}>
     <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.infoText}>
         

         <Image style={styles.userAvatar} source={{uri: 
post.photoURL}} />
            <UsernameText style={styles.name} >{post.displayName}. 
</UsernameText>
<CreatedAtText style={styles.timestamp}>. 
  {moment(post.timestamp).fromNow()}</CreatedAtText>
         </View>
        <View style={styles.container} >
  <ThoughtTitleText style={styles.feedItem}>{post.thoughtTitle}. 
  </ThoughtTitleText>
         </View>
    
      </View>
      </TouchableCmp>
      </View>
    );
  };

 render() {
    return (
       <View style={styles.container}>
         <Button
                onPress={() => {
                    Fire.shared.signOut();
                }}
                title="Log out"
            />

        <FlatList
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            style={styles.feed}
            data={this.state.latestPost}
            renderItem={( {item, index }) =>
             this.renderLatestPost(item, index)
            } 
        />
    </View>
     );
   }

    

   }

   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: Colors.background
  },
   feed: {
      marginHorizontal: 16
 },
 feedItem: {
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 2,
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginVertical: 2
},
name: {
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: "500",
    color: "#454D65"
},
timestamp: {
    fontSize: 11,
    color: "#C4C6CE",
    marginTop: 4
},
post: {
    marginTop: 16,
    fontSize: 14,
    color: "#838899"
},
postImage: {
    width: undefined,
    height: 150,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginVertical: 16
},
container: {
    flex:1,
    borderRadius: 10,
    padding:15,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'flex-end'
    },
    thought: {
    color: '#666',
    fontSize: 18,
    marginBottom: 5,
    alignItems: 'center' 
    },
 
    infoText:{
        flexDirection: "row"
    },
    // icons: {
    //     flexDirection: 'row'
    // },
    userAvatar: {
        backgroundColor: Colors.subheadings,
        borderColor: Colors.accent,
        borderWidth:3.5, 
        
        backgroundColor: Colors.maintext,
        marginEnd: 15,
        width: 35,
        height: 35,
        borderRadius: 20,
    } 
  });
```

Comment: Where are you getting `this.user` from inside the `addPost()`  at 
`displayName: this.user.displayName, photoURL: this.user.photoURL,`

Comment: from the `get user() {
        return firebase.auth().currentUser;
    }`

Comment: it doesn't seem you are updating the data on that i think. Why don't use access the data from the Firestore user data - `this.firestore.collection("users").doc(this.uid);` Then your post should get the right data.